# Firebase analytics shows activity in other countries

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-analytics

I am currently developing an app and I have an alpha release in Google play with associated testers and it is only available in Sweden.

I use `Firebase` to store data on a server for each user and I also use `Firebase` to login.

According to the `authorization` and `database` in my FireBase console, I am the only one who has tested it. However, in the analtyics, it says there has been activity in the `United States`! How is this possible? Is it something with Firebase's servers?

I thought about the rules for my database, I have the following:

```
{
  "rules": {
    // Give any logged in user admission to "users" so that they can create a new entrance for themselves
      ".write": "auth != null",
    ".read": "auth != null",
        "users": {
        "$user_id": {
            // Grants write access to the owner of this user account
          // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
         ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid && auth != null",
            ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid && auth != null"
        } 
        }
    }
}
```

Is something missing? 
The purpose is that only users that are signed in can write to the database and only to their specific folder.

I also have `inAppSubscription` which I tested yesterday, maybe that triggers something that makes it look like it appears in the `US`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that you enabled [Pre-launch Report](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/pre-launch-crash-reports) generation for your app.  You can confirm that by looking at the *Pre-launch Report* page in your Google Play Console.  Look for it under *Release Management*.

When you enable Pre-launch Report, each release of your app is run on a small number (~10) of devices using Firebase Test Lab.  This occurs even for alpha release and interal test tracks.

> **Pre-launch reports**: Summarizes the issues found when your alpha or beta test apps are tested automatically for device compatibility,
>   display issues, and security vulnerabilities on a wide range of
>   devices in Firebase Test Lab.

In your case, the Test Lab devices may be located in the US.

More details on [Pre-launch Report here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270?hl=en).

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the case. Wanted to make clear what it was since I am new to Firebase.